# How to measure the time spent in Postgres for a JDBC request?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have a program within the same machine as the Postgres server. The program creates JDBC requests to fetching tuples from the underlying Postgres and then perform some processing. For a JDBC request `resultSet = statement.executeQuery();`, how can I measure the time spent by Postgres, i.e., Postgres receive request and get the tuple from underlying disk and return the tuple? In other words, is there any more fine-grained way than measuring the time spent around executing above code, e.g.,

```
// timer start
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
// timer end
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can run `explain (analyze) select ...` which will show you how long the query runs on the server

Answer (score 0):

To measure the time spent on the server, set the PostgreSQL parameter `log_min_duration_statement` to a small value. Then every statement whose execution time exceeds the value will be logged, along with the time it took to process on the server.